# NASM interrupt x86 reference?

Tags: x86, nasm, system-calls, x86-16

I can't seem to find a good reference for NASM x86 interrupts on a Linux system. For example, what is `int 0x60` and how is it different from `int 0x80`?

Is there a manual somewhere which will list all the interrupt numbers which can be used in conjunction with the [int](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_%28x86_instruction%29) instruction?

Comment: +1 for the nostalgia... Below there are the breadcrumbs to home :-)

Comment: 0x60 and 0x80 are numbers, and NASM has not a single thing in the world to do with it -- it doesn't do anything with those numbers besides copy them from the input to the output.

Comment: 0x80 sounds like the syscall handler on various Linuxes. But as was mentioned, it depends on the system. int3 (separate instruction) on Windows is a break point into the debugger, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Linux** only uses `int 0x80` (or `sysenter` or `syscall`), with a call number in EAX.  Check `unistd_32.h`, and see

- [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989)
- [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)

---

**For 16-bit x86**, there's a long history of different interrupt numbers for different groups of interfaces, often with a call number in just AH.

There is the Ralph Brown's... It's soo many years...

- http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm

Instead of looking for a grain of sand in the desert, you could ask directions to Wiki:

BIOS

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call

DOS

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_API

Comment: +1 - Overwhelming... but it seems like the info is there... somewhere.

Comment: @Leguri Too much informations? :-) You asked for it :-) :-) Unless you need specific things, the BIOS and DOS Category should have everything you need.

Comment: Indeed I did :) Unless a more... shall we say... concise answer pops up, the tick's yours.

Comment: @LeguRi Good luck with your Real Mode DOS :-)

Comment: The question asked about Linux, but this accepted answer didn't even mention it >.<.  I updated with a couple relevant links for that, and added tags to the question that make it relevant for the BIOS answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any number from 1 to 255. Those are [software generated interrupts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_%28x86_instruction%29)

But the meaning/behaviour of it will pretty much depend on the operating system you are running it on! Or more exactly on the registered routine in the IDT that will handle that interrupt.

Comment: Interrupt 0 is also valid to use. Interrupts 0 to 31 are used by the CPU for faults too, but 0 is no different from 1 regarding that.

Comment: Note that in protected mode, the `int 0` is different from actually triggering a `#DE` exception, e.g. via `div edx`.  The IDT entries may not allow user-space to call into the exception handlers with `int`, especially `#PF`, only allow entry from triggering the faults "organically".